# Create menuitem with custom Font

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am using the below code

```
MenuItemFont* supportMenuItem = MenuItemFont::create("Contact us for support",
                                                          CC_CALLBACK_1(TempLogoLayer::supportMenuClicked, this));


 supportMenuItem->setPosition(Vec2(100,100));
 supportMenuItem->setFontName("Arial");
 supportMenuItem->setFontSize(16.0);


Menu *buttonsMenu = CCMenu::create(supportMenuItem, NULL);
buttonsMenu->setPosition(Vec2(0.0, 0.0));
this->addChild(buttonsMenu, 1)
```

But this menuitem is not taking font

Answer (score 2):

for arial you can use Label instead

```
auto lbRate = Label::createWithSystemFont("4 Rate", "Arial", 35.0);
auto menuRate = MenuItemLabel::create(lbRate, CC_CALLBACK_1(PlayerSkin::onRate, this));
auto menu = Menu::create(menuRate, NULL);
this->addChild(menu, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
item = MenuItemFont::create("item 1");
item->retain();

auto back = MenuItemFont::create("go back", CC_CALLBACK_1(RemoveMenuItemWhenMove::goBack, this));
```

This is for cocos2d-x 3.2 you could check in the sample directory MenuTest.cpp and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is really old, but someone else might probably stumble upon this post at some point:
For **Cocos2dx 3.6** Try:

`supportMenuItem->setFontNameObj("Arial");`

Also make sure that a font called "Arial" is in the Fonts directory

This will actually do the trick. OP was close.